# Redirect naked domain to https://www in aws serverless enviroment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a setup with Route 53, CloudFront, Api Gateway and Lambda. I need to redirect all requisitions to https://www

I tried to do that by changing domain.com record as an alias to www.domain .com at Route 53 but it seems to be only silent routing and not redirecting. I also search at cloud front configs but found nothing related to this.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating 2 cloud fronts, one that responds to www and other for the naked domain. In the one of naked domain you associate an api gateway to forward the request to a lambda, and at this lambda you do the redirect to www, where would be your real service. I don't know why but I have read that aws doesn't support redirections with query string, so this is a way to redirect from naked domain to www but only if you doens't need the query strings.